# Is it possible to trick a device into thinking a client is on the same subnet when it's actually virtualized?

Tags: networking, docker, subnet, socat

I'm a software engineer with only very basic networking skills, so I apologize in advance if I fumble a bit with my explanation here.

I have a physical device (specifically, an older model of [this network TV tuner](https://www.silicondust.com/product/hdhomerun-connect-duo/)) that *requires* clients be on the same subnet as it. Its client software does a broadcast to discover any tuners, and nothing can proceed until that discovery process succeeds. You can't just give it an IP address and be done with it.

I've set up a Docker-based stack (using Docker Compose) that successfully integrates with this device by using an `ipvlan` network so that each container is assigned its own IP address on my subnet. However, the support for `ipvlan` networks in Docker is rather woeful, so I'm having trouble getting the stack to work on my "production" Synology NAS even though it works perfectly fine on my dev Linux Mint machine (it seems `ipvlan` networks are simply not supported there).

So I'm exploring other options. One thing I wondered is whether I can fool the network tuner into thinking a client is on its subnet even if it isn't. And this is where I rapidly hit a wall in terms of networking knowledge.

I understand there's a tool called [`socat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socat) that might be able to help, and I even managed to get the initial discovery to work by running `socat` in a container like this (the network tuner is at `192.168.10.45`):

```
socat -d -d -v udp4-recvfrom:65001,broadcast,fork udp4-sendto:192.168.10.45:65001
```

However, clearly that wasn't enough because *only* the discovery worked - anything beyond that failed, so my guess is that, once discovered, communication switches to some other protocol/port and I would also need `socat` to "relay" that.

Basically, I'm unsure at this point whether what I'm hoping to achieve is even possible. What I'm imagining is that my Docker setup would include a container that only runs `socat` in such a way that it "relays" between other containers in that stack and the network tuner, fooling the tuner into thinking that it's communicating with a machine on the same subnet as my physical network, even though those containers would be on a `bridge` Docker network. Something along these lines:

[image]

I could also run `socat` as a daemon inside the backend container, which might simplify things.

Can anyone tell me if I'm barking up the wrong tree? Any pointers on how I might proceed to achieve this?

Comment: Check this documentation: https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/macvlan/